# How do I get outline numbering (e.g. ol tag) values via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I don't usually have to worry about rendering outline numbers, as it's handled automatically by display components (e.g. by HTML via the [`ol type=` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp)). However, I need an outline list to display outline numbers without the benefit of being able to use the built-in `ol` functionality.

Is there a way to leverage this outline numbering capability via Javascript? I have thought about doing it manually (i.e. I could simply return a character for a number 1 => a, 2 => b, etc.), but this would stop working once we got past 26 (need to restart at aa, ab, etc.). There also doesn't appear to be a built-in way to get roman numerals out, so this seems like it might be the wrong approach.

Comment: did you try `<ol type="a">`? it will start with 'aa' after 26th item

Comment: @ajaiJothi - I assume you're referring to HTML, and I specifically do not have HTML at the point I am at in the code.

Comment: What about css, can you use it?

Comment: I can use CSS, yes.

Comment: What about css counters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters. Specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counters#default_value_compared_to_upper_Roman

Comment: I’m not exactly sure if/how that would work with my JavaScript. Right now I’m feeding it to a text properly that’s being rendered via angular. This would be a totally different approach. Is it possible to skip DOM elements using this CSS approach? All the examples used OL items.